# Testing android app in different locale

Tags: android, locale, decimalformat

I have Android app where I do decimal formatting to the number. Some of our customers in Europe (like Germans) due to their numbering standards using ',' instead of '.'. How can I set/change Europe locale in my testing phone so that I can reproduce the issues. I go to `Settings -> Language and Keyboard Settings -> Select Language` I see "Locale" but even after changing to Spain/France nothing got changed.
Is any lib/settings available.Please let me know.

Comment: Are you using the strings.xml for internationalization? Can you post the relevant code for it and/or your Textview?

Comment: @cricket_007 Not the problem with the displaying text. It's problem with the `decimal formatting`.

Comment: Decimal formatting is an internationalization problem, and therefore an issue with displaying text. Please see http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/decimalformat.html

Comment: @cricket_007 I know the problem. I have been solved. But need to test that.I need a client environment to test.

Answer (score -1):

try setting->language & input -> language